# math.isclose(): Take only the decimals places into account

Tags: python, math, pytest

From my understanding of reading the [manual for math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) and for [pytest.approx](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-approx), only the decimal places of a float should be taken into account when checking if two floats are almost equal. But apparently, the whole numbers are also taken into account:

```
In [32]: math.isclose(48483.92, 48483.93, rel_tol=1e-06)
Out[32]: True

In [33]: math.isclose(48483.92, 48483.93, rel_tol=1e-07)
Out[33]: False

In [36]: math.isclose(484.92, 484.93, rel_tol=1e-04)
Out[36]: True

In [37]: math.isclose(484.92, 484.93, rel_tol=1e-05)
Out[37]: False

In [38]: 48483.92 == pytest.approx(48483.93, rel=1e-6)
Out[38]: True
```

Since I don't know how large will the whole numbers be in my program, is there a function that checks if two floats are almost equal, where 48483.92 is not equal to 48483.93 if I set the tolerance to 1e-6, but only to 1e-2?

Comment: Looks like you want to set the absolute tolerance (`abs_tol`) instead of the relative, if I understand you correctly (e.g. `abs_tol=1e-2`, if you are only interested in the first 2 decimal places).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Ouch, wasn't very obvious for me from the docs! At least not from the docs for pytest (where I started reading). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the two optional tolerance parameters how you want:

```
math.isclose(48483.92, 48483.93,rel_tol=0, abs_tol=1e-1)
```

Because of floating point issues

```
math.isclose(48483.92, 48483.93,rel_tol=0, abs_tol=1e-2)
```

evaluates to false, so you should provide a little cushion for 2 decimal places, perhaps `abs_tol=0.5e-1`.

While it is possible to do this, it often isn't advisable. There is a *reason* why the default for `math.isclose()` is to test for relative rather than absolute error. Absolute error is harder to interpret since its significance depends upon the scale of the numbers.